# Products not adding to Codeigniter cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I have an issue with the Codeigniter cart.  I have created the code and checked it but every time I add the same product it only updates all the information of the product but does not add a new one.  For example two exact shirts but different size or colors.  I searched around on here for a solution but have not yet come up with one.

My controller code

```
public function addToCart() {
$data = $this->input->post();

$id = $data['id'];
$qty = $data['qty']; 
$color = $data['color'];
$cart = $this->cart->contents();
$exists = false;
$rowid = '';

foreach($cart as $item):
    if($item['id'] == $id && $item['color'] == $color):
        $exists = true;
        $rowid = $item['rowid'];
        $qty = $item['qty'] + $qty;
    else:
        // if statement does not equal
    endif;
endforeach;

if($exists):
    $this->product_model->update_cart_item($rowid, $qty);
    redirect('dashboard');
else:
    $this->product_model->add_cart_item();
    redirect('dashboard');
endif;

 }
```

My model code

```
public function update_cart_item($rowid, $qty){
    $data = array(
            'rowid' => $rowid,
            'qty' => $qty
    );

$this->cart->update($data);
}

public function add_cart_item(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');
    $price = $this->input->post('price');
    $color = $this->input->post('color');
    $photo = $this->input->post('photo');
    $type = $this->input->post('type');
    $data = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'price' => $price,
            'name' => $name,
            'color' => $color,
            'photo' => $photo,
            'type' => $type
    );

$this->cart->insert($data); 
}
```

The updating portion of an already existing product works fine.  The part that does not is when its the same product but a different color for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to process some action on every of your product, try with this:

```
public function addToCart() {
    $data = $this->input->post();

    foreach($cart as $item):

        $id = $data['id'];
        $qty = $data['qty']; 
        $color = $data['color'];
        $cart = $this->cart->contents();
        $exists = false;
        $rowid = '';

        if($item['id'] == $id && $item['color'] == $color):
            $exists = true;
            $rowid = $item['rowid'];
            $qty = $item['qty'] + $qty;

            if($exists):
                $this->product_model->update_cart_item($rowid, $qty);
            else:
                $this->product_model->add_cart_item();

            endif;
        else:
            // if statement does not equal
        endif;
    endforeach;
    redirect('dashboard');
 }
```

You would like to set `$exists` to false before checking any next product.
After all, you need just redirection to dashboard when everything in loop is done. Hope it would work.

Comment: I used what you made and sadly that did not work either.  I think the problem seems to be on in the cart itself.  It will not create a new row id with different colors.  Maybe I will just pipe it through the options portion of the reserved names.

Comment: piping it through the options area of the cart still did not produce proper results.  the same product but different type is still being overwritten.

Comment: Np. Glad you succeeded.